# How can I find this distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, problem-solving, density-function

The random variable $X$ has the probability density function $f_X(x)$ represented
in the figure
[image: figure]

How can I find the $F_X(x)$ (distribution function)? And how can I find the value of $C$ when $P(|X|\le  0.5) \ge C$?

Comment: by integrating the pdf function from $-\infty$  to $c$ then at the end replace $c$ by $x$. You have the distribution function

Comment: yeah but I have two function in there. fx(x) = x+1 and fx(x) = 1-x. Which should I use?

Comment: No, you have a single piecewise function, $f_X(x) = \begin{cases}x+1 & -1 \le x \le 0 \\ 1-x & 0 \le x \le 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: Format your posts using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating the triangular density you will easy find

$$  F_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x<-1$} \\
x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2},  & \text{if $-1\leq x <0$} \\
x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2},  & \text{if $0 \leq x <1$} \\
1,  & \text{if $x \geq 1$}
\end{cases}$$

To calculate the requested probability

$$\mathbb{P}[|X|>0.5]=0.25$$

it is immediate to calculate the area of the two triangles in the tails (you will do it by mind, without any complicate calculation)

Answer (score 3):

In general, to find the CDF $F_X(x)$ given the PDF $f_X(x)$, you should integrate:
$$
   F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t) \,dt.
$$
In this case, $f_X$ is a piecewise function defined separately for $x<-1$, $-1 \le x < 0$, $0 \le x < 1$, and $x \ge -1$. So you have to integrate separately on those intervals:

- For $x < -1$, $F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t) \,dt = \int_{-\infty}^x 0 \,dt = 0$.
- For $-1 \le x < 0$, $F_X(x)$ can be broken up as $\int_{-\infty}^{-1} f_X(t)\,dt + \int_{-1}^x f_X(t)\,dt$, which becomes $0 + \int_{-1}^x (t+1)\,dt$.
- For $0 \le x < 1$, $F_X(x)$ can be broken up as $\int_{-\infty}^{-1} f_X(t)\,dt + \int_{-1}^0 f_X(t)\,dt + \int_0^x f_X(t)\,dt$, which becomes $0 + \int_{-1}^0 (t+1)\,dt + \int_0^x (1-t)\,dt$.
- Finally, for $x \ge 1$, we have to integrate over all four parts, but we expect that at this point $F_X(x) = 1$.

Another way to phrase it is that if we have intervals $(-\infty,-1) \cup [-1,0) \cup [0,1) \cup [1,\infty)$ on which $f_X$ has different definitions, we:

1. Set $F_X(t) = \int_{-\infty}^x 0\,dt$ for $x \in (-\infty,-1)$ and use this to compute $F_X(-1)$. (We'll get $0$.)
2. Set $F_X(t) = F_X(-1) + \int_{-1}^x (t+1)\,dt$ for $x \in [-1,0)$ and use this to compute $F_X(0)$.
3. Set $F_X(t) = F_X(0) + \int_0^x (1-t)\,dt$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and use this to compute $F_X(1)$. (We'll get $1$.)
4. Set $F_X(t) = F_X(1) + \int_1^x 0\,dt$ for $x \in (1,\infty)$.

The idea is that on every interval, $F_X(x)$ should be the whole probability of the previous intervals, plus some portion of the probability of the current interval.

---

Finally, to find $\Pr[|X| \le 0.5]$ or $\Pr[-0.5 \le X \le 0.5]$, we can take $F_X(0.5) - F_X(-0.5)$.